# How to create this particular view in android studio?

Tags: android, xml

[Link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlTq2.jpg)

I am trying to make an app which will be displaying multiple cards like these. But I am not able to create this view.

I tried using a constraint layout and adjusting the smaller card within it but it is not working

Comment: Can you elaborate what didn't work when adjusting the smaller card? Show the code you used? I think this should work when using a constraintlayout

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: Using ConstraintLayout it's simple. We are not ChatGPT, so you have to do that work for yourself and ask us something only when you could became stucked and not at the very beginning.....